# How could I improve my nodeJS program

Tags: node.js, callback, promise

I used promises, callbacks and external API for the firt time but I'm not sure that's the best way to use them.

My program traslates words from a langage to another using a langae Pivot and [systran.io](http://www.systran.io/) API.

the function `Translate` will translate word and send response via a callback.

then in the POST request I used promises to chain tasks.

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');

var router = express.Router();

router.post("/", function(req, res) {
    console.log
    var resultat
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        translate(req.query.source, "en", req.query.content, function(resa) {
            resolve(resa);

        })
    }).then(function(resolve) {
        console.log(resolve);
        translate("en", req.query.target, resolve, function(resa2) {
            console.log(resa2);

        })
    });
});

function translate(source, target, content, callback) {
    let result;
    result = request("https://api-platform.systran.net/translation/text/translate?input=" + content + "&source=" + source + "&target=" + target + "&key=xxxxxxxx-783f-4f90-aea4-7fb357016647", function(err, data, body) {
        body = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(body);

        callback(body.outputs[0].output)
    })
}
module.exports = router;
```

Is there a best way to write my program which is already working ?

Comment: Consider what happens if the translate function returns an error. Typically one would use the reject function in the promise to pass it to some catch at the end of your promise chain

Comment: If this is already working code, then you should read the posting rules at http://codereview.stackexchange.com and post there.